# Value not changing correctly in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following method in one of my classes called Board. Board has an array of 120 Squares, which is another class from my program.

```
public class Board{

private Square[] square = new Square[120];
...
```

Each Square has an int row and an int column.

```
public class Square extends JButton{
public int row;
public int column;
...
```

The method itself is supposed to figure out what the row and column is for every Square inside

```
    void setSquares() {
    int ones;
    int tenths;
    Square s = new Square();
    Insets squareMargin = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    s.setMargin(squareMargin);
    for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++){

        ones = getNdigit(i, 1);
        tenths = getNdigit(i, 2);

        //set row && set column
        if ((tenths >= 2 && tenths <= 9) && (ones >= 1 && ones <= 8)){
            s.row = tenths - 1;
            s.column = ones;

        } else{
            s.row = 0;
            s.column = 0;
        }
        square[i] = s;
        System.out.println(square[0].toString());

    }
```

So at the end of the method, I expect that square[34] has a row of 2 and a column of 4. However, the actual result is always the same as where the for loop ended (square[34] has a row and column of 0).
If the for loop was changed to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++){
```

then square[34] has a row of 4 and a column of 4.

Comment: 1. You forgot to ask a question. 2. What value is not changing correctly? Provide sample input and output (both expected and actually received)

Comment: The value of both int and columns wasn't changing correctly, My question was why. I provided sample data in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating only one instance of `Square` and use it throughout the for loop. Move the instantiation inside the for loop so each instance stored will be different.

To answer your question in the comment:

```
Square s = new Square();
```

Allocates some space in memory to store the `Square` instance (where you can set values to its members). so now `s` references that space in memory.

```
square[i] = s;
```

so now `square[i]` references that same space (thus having the same member values). so for every `i` all `square[i]` references to the same place (the same instance of `Square`). But if you allocate `s` one each iteration then `s` will reference a new square and each `square[i]` will reference a different `Square` instance

Comment: This is all I needed to do. I'm amazed. Do you mind if I ask why does this happen? The value of s changes in every loop, why does square[i] change with it?

Comment: This makes so much sense now. I've been banging my head against the wall for hours now, and you just came in like a dose of Vicodin. I can't be grateful enough.